# Should I attach the local media stream to the WebRtc Connection before I create an offer?

Tags: webrtc

Is there any difference between these two ways to create a connection:

1. Create an offer and send it to a callee, after receive the answer and then attach the local media to the connection,
2. Attach the local media to the connection,  create an offer and then send it to a callee

Answer (score 2):

Early "**attach**" is opted for **local** session description; which becomes "**remote** description" for answerer. Otherwise, you need to **renegotiate** streams by creating offer/answer again.